# Define hadoop FS path inside shell script or perl script

Tags: java, perl, shell, hadoop

How can I define my path for HDFS inside my shell or perl script so that it picks the input files stored in hdfs and executes the script . It executes correctly under the local file system, but i may need in hdfs

For example , I have part of the script below defined for executing in local path

Define names of folders to be watched

```
$folderRoot = **'/home/local'**;
```

A Java pgm

```
$oscmd = "java -classpath **/home/local**";
#print "forking Java PGM [$thisFile] [$oscmd]\n";
$oscmdResult = `$oscmd`;
print "$oscmdResult\n";
```

1. How to define the HDFS path inside Shell or perl script
2. How to define in the Java classpath in Java Pgm for HDFS so when the shell script is called it invokes the Java pgm as well

   ## My objective : the perl/shell script  needs to pick the input files in HDFS and execute it successfully

Answer (score 0):

Mount HDFS into some place and then define a path to this place.

Comment: tks for ur suggestion, so do you mean to say ,I create a directory in the HDFS  and  do a mount cmd like " mount /export/hdfs." and put this path in the script "/export/hdfs"

Comment: @user3764303 Content of the script has to be available. You have some options. Make a copy and run this copy. Mount it. You have to get the content anyway.

Comment: I have added part of my perl script here for ur reference for further assistance , tks in advance. I need to change the path of the home/local to HDFS path here. If you can explain the options in detail, that would be gr8